# How to move a polyline with a marker in google maps api V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Hello I want to  write un programme in Google maps javascript API V3 and I want to know how can I move a marker and at the same time move the polyline too.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be create a [**symbol on the polyline**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#PolylineSymbols) and additionally  set the `draggable`-option of the polyline to `true`

Comment: thank you very much,but in my programme, I have to first create some markers and then create some polylines. Because I want to creat some different conditions: move the marker alone or move the marker with the polyline or move the polyline alone. But any way thank u very much!